# Oracle driver probably not in class path using task "gradle jar"

Tags: java, oracle, gradle, jdbc

I write simple program in Java that opens connections to oracle database and then closes connection.

I setup project with gradle as vanilla project. This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre'
    implementation 'com.oracle:ojdbc8:19.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// Define the main class for the application
mainClassName = 'lab2.jdbc.App'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
            'Main-Class': 'lab2.jdbc.App'
        )
    }
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
package lab2.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", "user");
        props.put("password", "password");
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", props);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected!");
            try {
                connection.close();
                System.out.println("Successfully disconnected");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to disconnect: " + e);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the project using task `run` it works fine:

```
> Task :run
Successfully connected!
Successfully disconnected

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

But when I try to run the jar it does not work:

```
./gradlew jar
java -jar build/libs/lab2-jdbc.jar
Failed to connect: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your `build.gradle` file:

1) The Oracle JDBC dependency should be:

`implementation 'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0'`

2) You're not including classes from your dependencies to create a fat jar.  In order to do that, you need to change the following:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'lab2.jdbc.App')
    }
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.filter { it.exists() }.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you found this configuration?
Could you say me how to cope with such problems?